# Почему не работает отправка данных в БД?

Tags: php, база-данных

```
<?php

class dataProcessing
{
    private $login;
    private $password;

    public function getData($login, $pass)
    {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->password = md5($pass);
    }

    public function getPass()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }
}

$date = new dataProcessing;
$date->getData($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);

if (isset($_POST['sing-in'])) {
    $date = new dataProcessing;
    $date->getData($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "testlogpass");
    if (!$con) {
        echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($con) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $sql = "
    SELECT * FROM `loginpasstest` WHERE 1;
    INSERT INTO loginpasstest
    (login, password)
    VALUES ('$date->getLogin', '$date->getPass');";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo 'ERROR SQL';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
};

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно

```
>     $sql = "
>     SELECT * FROM `loginpasstest` WHERE 1;
>     INSERT INTO loginpasstest
>     (login, password)
>     VALUES ('$date->getLogin', '$date->getPass');";
```

Надо так:

```
    $sql = "
    INSERT INTO loginpasstest
    (login, password)
    VALUES ('$date->getLogin', '$date->getPass')";
```